# Could I put four functions into one?

Tags: javascript, addition, calculator, subtraction

I am not sure if I am wording this correctly, but basically I have wrote out 4 functions (I have to build a calculator) and each function is for dividing, adding, multiplying and subtracting. Is there any way that I can add all these 'commands' into one function instead of having four separate ones?

Thank you.

```
function add (num1, num2){
    var intOutput= parseInt(num1)+parseInt(num2);
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=intOutput;
}

function subtract (num1, num2){
    var intOutput= parseInt(num1)-parseInt(num2);
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=intOutput;
}

function multiply (num1, num2){
    var intOutput= parseInt(num1)*parseInt(num2);
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=intOutput;
}


function divide (num1, num2){
    var intOutput= parseInt(num1)/parseInt(num2);
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=intOutput;
}
```

Comment: You could, but why would you?  Is this homework?

Comment: Are you referring to adding `if` statements in one function instead of having them separate?

Comment: #trying to find a simpler way, as I plan on adding more content to the javascript file and would rather make everything as short as is allowed.

Comment: Why not use the math functions already in Javascript?

Comment: Your functions should return a value and you should have this statement only once document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=intOutput;

Comment: thanks everyone, think it has been nailed :)

Comment: Wow 6 answers in 8 mins

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you want a general function which will conditionally perform a requested action. Something like this should work:

```
function calculate(num1, num2, action)
{
    if (action == 'add') {
        //...
    } else if (action == 'subtract') {
        //...
    } else if (action == 'multiply') {
        //...
    } else if (action == 'divide') {
        //...
    }
}
```

EDIT: For sake of readability and long-term maintainability, you may still want to keep the actual actions in separate functions, and simply call those from the various `if` branches.

Answer (score 1):

You can refactor all the DOM code as such:

```
function proc(op, num1, num2) {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = op(parseInt(num1), parseInt(num2));
}
```

Then using these simple helpers:

```
var addOp = function (a, b) { return a + b; };
var subOp = function (a, b) { return a - b; };
var multOp = function (a, b) { return a * b; };
var divOp = function (a, b) { return a / b; };
```

You can do any op you desire:

```
proc(addOp, num1, num2);
proc(subOp , num1, num2);
proc(multOp , num1, num2);
proc(divOp , num1, num2);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function calculate(type, num1, num2) {
    var _in  = parseInt(num1, 10),
        _out = parseInt(num2, 20),
        output = 0;

    switch(type) {
        case 'add':
            output = _in + _out;
            break;
        case 'subtract':
            output = _in - _out;
            break;
        case 'multiply':
            output = _in * _out;
            break;
        case 'divide':
            output = _in / _out;
            break;
    }

    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output;
}
```

to be used as

```
calculate('add', 10, 20); // 30
calculate('multiply', 10, 20); // 200
// etc...
```

If you make sure the string is just a number an operator and a number, you could use eval for some fun (all though eval is evil)

```
function calculate(str) {
    if (/\d+(\*|\-|\+|\/)\d+/.test(str))
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = eval(str);
}
```

Then you could just do

```
calculate('20*10')
calculate('20+100')
calculate('1000/100')
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/dBtr8/)

Answer (score 1):

You can abstract out common behavior using function variables:

```
function calculateAndDisplay(num1, num2, operation) {
    var intOutput= operation(num1, num2);
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=intOutput;
}

function add(num1, num2) {
    calculateAndDisplay(num1, num2, function(a, b) { return a + b; });
}

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this sounds like homework, I'll give you a homework-y answer.

You know you can call a function from anywhere, including another function, so it's totally possible to create "one function to rule them all."

For example:

```
function helloJohn() {
    console.log('Hello John');
}

function helloJane() {
    console.log('Hello Jane');
}

function hello(name) {
    if (name === 'John') {
        helloJohn();
    } else if (name === 'Jane') {
        helloJane();
    }
}
```

I could easily change my `hello` function to include the `helloJohn` and `helloJane` functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this if you add another parameter for the operation performed. Maybe a switch to do each operation.

```
function operate(n1,n2,op){
    var output;    
    switch(op){
        case 'add':
            output = n1+n2;
            break;
        case 'sub':
            output= n1-n2;
            break;
        case 'div':
            output = n1/n2;
            break;
        case 'mul':
            output = n1*n2;

    }
    document.getElementById('output').innerHtml = output
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var Calculator = {
  add: function (num1, num2) {
    var intOutput= parseInt(num1)+parseInt(num2);
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=intOutput;
  },
  subtract: function (num1, num2) {
    var intOutput= parseInt(num1)-parseInt(num2);
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=intOutput;
  },
  multiply: function (num1, num2) {
    var intOutput= parseInt(num1)*parseInt(num2);
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=intOutput;
  },
  divide: function (num1, num2) {
    var intOutput= parseInt(num1)/parseInt(num2);
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=intOutput;
  }
};

Calculator.add(4, 5);
Calculator.divide(20, 10);
```